# Как выбрать сеть в java программе осуществляющей обмен по udp в режиме Multicast

Tags: java, udp

Приложение на Java осуществляет передачу данных по протоколу UDP в режиме Multicast с другим компьютером. На этой же машине установлен VirtualBox.

Вот код отправки данных:

```
private final static String IP_ADDR = "224.1.1.201";
DatagramSocket socket;
public void sending() {
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    group = InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDR);
    sendingDataBuffer = parserData(dataBuffer);
    DatagramPacket packet 
    = new DatagramPacket(sendingDataBuffer, sendingDataBuffer.length, group, SERVICE_PORT);
    socket.send(packet);
}
```

Проблема оказалась в том, что программа отправляла пакеты в сеть virtualBox, поэтому я их не мог ни получить на приемной стороне, ни увидеть в Wireshark.
Как мне в Java коде указать в какую сеть оправлять пакеты?
Если отключаю сетевое соединение virtualBox, то пакеты начинают отправляться через стандартное сетевое соединение на другой компьютер.
Почему мое приложение отправляет данные именно в эту сеть?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/333584

Comment: Я видел эту ссылку. Сделал как там написано. Первую сеть в virtualbox настроил как NAT, вторую как мост. Но пакеты все равно уходят в сетевое соединение virtualbox, а не в Eth1

Answer (score 1):

Проблема возникает из-за того, что Microsoft присваивает метрики интерфейса на основе собственной скорости соединения, сообщаемой драйвером в Windows 7. Поскольку это всего 1 ГБ, возникает конфликт метрик.
Вот решение, которое мне помогло:

1. Откройте Центр управления сетями и общим доступом

   - Нажмите «Изменить настройки адаптера»
   - Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши « Сеть только для хоста VirtualBox
     », перейдите в «Свойства».
2. На странице "Свойства" нажмите "Дополнительно..."
3. На вкладке "Дополнительные параметры TCP/IP" на вкладке "Параметры IP" снимите флажок "Автоматическая метка" и введите от 800 и выше.